# Eager loading of sub-class collections in HQL

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to solve a N+1 select problem involving a HQL query that loads a collection of objects all of the same base type.

To solve this I would like to eagerly fetch some references and collections that are defined within some of the sub classes. Something like:

```
select c
from BaseClass c
   left join fetch c.PropertyOfSubClassA
   left join fetch c.PropertyOfSubClassB
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

To fix select n+1 problems, I suggest you try [batch fetching](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch) instead.